# Is an ngrx action supposed to trigger all the reducers

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a pretty simple app, and am using ngrx for the first time

**reducer.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
 imports:[
  StoreModule.forRoot({
   sliceA: AReducer,
   sliceB: BReducer 
  })
 ]
})
```

**AReducer.ts**

```
export function AReducer(state, action : AActions) {
  switch(...)
}
```

**BReducer.ts**

```
export function AReducer(state, action : BActions) {
  switch(...)
}
```

**someComponent.ts**

```
store.dispatch(new AAction());
```

Now what I would have hoped is ngrx would only trigger AReducer and not BReducer, but I see it triggering both. It's also jarring because the second argument to BReducer is an AAction, even though I parameterize the second argument to the type BAction.

So is there any way I can have ngrx only trigger the relevant reducers? Or is the design that it triggers all of them, and the irrelevant ones just trivially return the store?

Comment: This is weird, the same thing happens for me. What is I'm working on a gigantic app? Will all my reducers be triggered on every request? It doesn't make since.

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, this is the typical `NgRx` behaviour. For `NgRx`, all `actions` are independent/unrelated regardless of which file you define them in. Sames goes for `reducers`, you'll use different files to make it maintainable, but `NgRx` goes through all the reducers for each action dispatched.

However, what you'd typically do in a `reducer` is that, when a `case` to handle an action is implemented, if you `return` from that `case`, `NgRx` stops looking for the rest of the reducers.

So in your case:

```
export function AReducer(state, action : AActions) {
  switch(action.type){
    case actions.AAction:
    return {...state} // this is when NgRx stops looking for the case to handle an action
  }
}
```

Comment: "all actions are unique". This is not true, it depends on the action type.

Comment: Thanks, I mean to say they are independent... I'll edit.

Comment: How can I leverage this behavior to trigger all reducers?

Answer (score 0):

It drove me crazy lol

As written in the NgRX guide:

> When an action is dispatched, all registered reducers receive the action

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers